# Downloading actual .yaml, .pgm or octomap binary files from roboearth

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, roboearth, environment

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have uploaded my lab's environment owl description (2D occupancy map), 2D occupancy grid map in .pgm and .yaml file formats on to roboearth DB. But this has been done through roboearth web interface. (http://api.roboearth.org)

Although we can do this through POST command. Could anyone please let me know if there are any ros commands through which these files can be downloaded or this can be done only through JSON (GET command -> tried this but this just gives owl description of environment and not actual file) ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/75850/downloading-actual-.yaml,-.pgm-or-octomap-binary-files-from-roboearth./) by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 320 on 2013-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the re_comm and re_comm_core packages that wrap the HTTP webservice interface into ROS services wiki.ros.org/re_comm

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2013-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2